# Circle draw by mouse click issue

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent

I am learning Java for a few weeks and I am having a problem with a "project".

I am trying to write a simple (obviously not for me) program that draws a circle on the canvas by mouse click, on the coordinates where I clicked with the mouse!

Here is my code:

MyGame3.java
    package mygame3;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyGame3 extends JFrame{
    int WIDTH, HEIGHT;

    Image dbImage;
    Graphics dbg;

    static ArrayList<Circle> circles;

    public MyGame3(){
        WIDTH = 600;
        HEIGHT = 600;

        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setTitle("My Game 3");
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                System.out.println(e.getX() + " " + e.getY());
                circles.add(new Circle(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        draw(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        if (circles.size() > 0){
            for (Circle c: circles){
                c.draw(g);
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        MyGame3 main = new MyGame3();

        if (circles.size() > 0){
            for (Circle c: circles){
                Thread circle = new Thread(c);
                circle.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Circle.java:

```
package mygame3;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public class Circle implements Runnable{    

    Ellipse2D circle;

    public Circle(int x, int y){

        circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 30, 30);
    }

    public void draw (Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawOval((int)circle.getX(),
                   (int)circle.getY(),
                   (int)circle.getWidth(),
                   (int)circle.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(2);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error I am getting with 2 clicks on the screen:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mygame3.MyGame3.main(MyGame3.java:59)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mygame3.MyGame3.draw(MyGame3.java:47)
    at mygame3.MyGame3.paint(MyGame3.java:42)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:819)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mygame3.MyGame3.draw(MyGame3.java:47)
    at mygame3.MyGame3.paint(MyGame3.java:42)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:819)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
245 386
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mygame3.MyGame3$1.mousePressed(MyGame3.java:33)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6502)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2022)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
245 386
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mygame3.MyGame3$1.mousePressed(MyGame3.java:33)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6502)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2022)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Thanks for any response!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with...

I don't see any where you initialise the `circles` `ArrayList`...

Then move onto...

You should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, apart from the fact that they are not double buffered, they also normally involve a series of additional components which make up the top level container.

Instead, you should create a custom component, extending from `JPanel` for example, and override it's `paintComponent` method.  Swing components are double buffered so you don't need to do anything special with this.

I also don't see why `Circle` should need to implement `Runnable`.

If you want to perform some kind of animation, you should use a single thread which is used to modify the entire state, which should then be rendered as a single step.  This allows you to keep things in sync and prevents you from starving the system.

You should also avoid modifying or updating the state of the UI from within any `paintXxx` method. For example, don't call `repaint` in you paint methods...

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details